# How to access methods of User Controls passed as parameter to a Constructor

Tags: c#, user-controls, itemplate

I am passing an instance of UserControl as this to the Constructor of the Class which inherits the Page Class and Itemplate Interface , I am saving the instance of type userControl , Now How can I access the methods of the user Control. 
For Ex, MyUserControl file name is uc_test and The Class datagridtemplate:Page, Itemplate

My UserControl has partial class name uc_test and have method

```
public int addtwonumbers()
{
 return 10+20;
}

datadatagridtemplate x = new datagridtemplate(this); //new instance
```

In the datagridtemplate.cs file :

```
public datagridtemplate(UserControl uc){}
```

in In one of method of datagridtemplate class I want to do following

```
int sum = uc.addtwonumbers();
```

Now I wanted to access all the methods and properties defined in the uc_test , how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Cast the user control to your type in the constructor: `uc = uc as MyType`

Comment: here Mytype is the class file you are referring ? i.e. uc_test ?

Comment: It would be clearer for everyone if you provided a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think so, can't tell from what you have posted here. Whatever you defined the class as i.e `public class MyType : UserControl`

Comment: It Says type or namespace could be found (missing directive or assembly reference) ,

Answer (score 0):

> My UserControl has partial class name uc_test

As suggested by Jack Miller, cast your generic UserControl reference to the correct type that you created:

```
uc_test ucTst = (uc_test)uc;
int sum = ucTst.addtwonumbers();
```

Comment: I tried to do it but it says it could not be found, I trying calling the namespace and including in the c# file , but it throws an error.